# Click or Touch event on TableLayout

Tags: android, xamarin

I have asked a similar on the Xamarin forum with no reply.  There seem to be no Xamarin samples.

In my .axml I have a TableLayout inside a ScrollView inside a RelativeLayout.  The table can have a number of rows.  However, I want to perform a button click if I just touch the whole table, whether there is anything in there or not.  Normally, the child view gets the event, and that's not what I want.

I have tried:

- Deriving a class from my tablelayout that implemented OnTouchEvent
  and OnInterceptTouchEvent.  No matter what these methods returned, I
  could never get the event for the whole table.
- Just processing the touch or click event on the tablelayout:
  `myTableLayout.Touch += (sender, e) => { do something };`
  With no result.
- Implementing OnTouch, only called if I press outside any view.

My closest (almost works): implementing touch on the scrollview:

```
sv.Touch += (sender, e) => {
    if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Down) {
        sendButton.PerformClick();
    } else {
        (sender as ScrollView).OnTouchEvent(e.Event);
    }
};
```

The trouble with that is that when I just want to scroll, there is still a Down event and I get the PerformClick when I don't want it.

Is there a Xamarin sample that really does this?

Thanks

Comment: In short, you want to make the `TableLayout` not clickable so will the `ScrollView` get the click event, in the meanwhile keep the `ScrollView`  scrollable?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I just tried this -- myTableLayout.Clickable = false, but it made no difference.  The ScrollView still gets the MotionEventActions.Down touch event whenever I try to scroll, and I get the dialog, which I don't want in this case.  The ScrollView never gets a click event.  The only way not to get the dialog when scrolling is to scroll while touching existing text in there, because the child is intercepting the event.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just making it an EditText instead of worrying about tables and table cells.  Touching and scrolling work fine now.